# Property or indexer "Attachments" cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, email, attachment

I´m trying to send mail with image attachment, but it still throwing error 
 (*Property or indexer "Attachments" cannot be assigned to -- it is read only *)

```
string pathToPic = @"c:\MyDir\Img\img"+ automaticalyGeneratedNumber.toString() + ".png";


using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = Environment.MachineName,
                Body = "PC NAME : " + Environment.MachineName + "\r\nIP ADRESS : " + Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1],
                Attachments = new Attachment(@"c:\MyDir\Img" + "/img" + (Saving.CountImagesTaken(@"c:\MyDir\Img") - 1).ToString() + ".png"),
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why complicate the code like that. You need to use `message.Attachments.Add` since the `Attachments` property is read-only :

```
var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = Environment.MachineName,
    Body = "PC NAME : " + Environment.MachineName + "\r\nIP ADRESS : " + Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1],
};
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"c:\MyDir\Img" + "/img" + (Saving.CountImagesTaken(@"c:\MyDir\Img") - 1).ToString() + ".png"));
using (message)
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```